# iOS vs OSX Bluetooth for hearing aid?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, iphone

**Can anyone explain to me the differences between bluetooth implementation in iOS vs OSX?**

I wear a type of hearing aid called a **BAHA** (Cochlear BAHA 5). I can connect (stream music) directly to this aid with my iphone X (using bluetooth), but am completely unable to do so in OSX (2020 Macbook Pro). I'm confused as to why this should be, and I'm aware of others in the BAHA communiy who are similarly puzzled.

I find it hard to believe that the hardware can be significantly different, yet Apple's bluetooth connector does not "see" my aid on the Macbook. I did find an app that will "see" that the aid is there (*Bluetooth Inspector* by George Garside), but it doesn't allow connection and I can't stream anything to the aid through that.

Can anyone shed any light on why this should be so? I did try to email Apple (Craig Federighi himself) but got no response. I'd really like to be able to stream music from my Macbook to my aids, and I know there others who would also welcome this facility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that a solution exists at the moment.

In a recent post
[Streaming to hearing aids on iOS, but not OSX - why](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/streaming-to-hearing-aids-on-ios-but-not-osx-why.2289873/)
I found this final entry:

> Just to finish this thread off, I got in touch with Cochlear, who indicated that the lack of direct streaming to the BAHA on a Macbook is a software issue, rather than any hardware incompatibility. I did raise this with Apple some time ago, but never get any response. We'll just have to wait until all the bright young things at Apple start to lose their hearing, I guess...

The problem might be solved with the help of some intermediate
device, such as your iPhone, but I can't help with that.

Comment: I'd still be interested to know why there should be some difference between bluetooth on iOS and that on OSX, and what the difference is.

Comment: The above says that direct streaming on OSX is different, perhaps in the protocol version that is used for streaming. Cochlear Support might agree to give more information (as they seem to be answering queries).